# Shortest Path between large area -- RAM issue

Tags: r, shortest-path

I built a shortest path algorithm that finds and stores the distance of the optimal path between neighboring grid cells using a friction surface as an input. It works beautifully but I am facing RAM memory issues to do so for a very large area, which is my ultimate goal. My object of interest is `tau`, the bilateral distances' matrix below.

```r
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(gdistance)
library(geosphere)

load('grid2.rdata') # small grid of locations whose bilateral path I need to calculate
# load('grid.rdata') # very large grid which I would like to use
grid <- area
# friction surface:
friction <- raster('test.tif')
# standardizing projections:
grid <- spTransform(grid, friction@crs)
# cropping friction into aoi area:
friction <- crop(friction,grid)

# making it a transition matrix:
friction <- transition(friction, function(x) 1/mean(x), 8)

# Now identifying which cells are neighbors of the others:
tau <- as.matrix(gTouches(grid, byid = T))
rownames(tau) <- colnames(tau) <- 1:nrow(grid)
# tau is symmetric -- replace upper triangle 
# part with 0 (cuts iterations by half!):
tau[upper.tri(tau)] <- 0
ll <- sum(tau) # number of total iterations

# Calculating routes between neighboring cells:
ii<-0 # counter
cat('2. Calculating shortest route between cells:\n')
for (i in 1:nrow(grid))  {
  for (j in which(as.numeric(tau[i,])==1)) {
    ii <- ii+1
    pp <- SpatialPoints(coords = matrix(c(grid@data[i,long],grid@data[i,lat], grid@data[j,long], grid@data[j,lat]),2,2,byrow=T), proj4string = grid@proj4string)
    d <- shortestPath(friction,
                      pp[1,],
                      pp[2,],
                      output = "SpatialLines"
    )
    # Desired outputs:
    if (ii==1) {routes <- d} else {routes <- rbind(routes, d)}
    if (ii==1) {locs <- pp} else {locs <- rbind(locs, pp)}
    # storing the distance (in km):
    tau[i,j] <- lengthLine(d)/1000

  }

}
```

It works pretty well and if I want to visualize the output with

```r
plot(grid)
plot(locs,pch=T,add=T)
plot(routes,add=T)
```

I obtain the image attached. How could I do the same for a very large area (`grid.rdata` at the beginning of the code) in a more memory-efficient way?

link to the data used: [friction surface](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m2bsylywkitzz0b/test.tif?dl=1), [grid](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mp7z4lm481167rx/grid.rdata?dl=1), [grid2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6qspylbnt8ython/grid2.rdata?dl=0).

[image]